# How to find and replace the value in XML according to preset parameters

Tags: php, xml-parsing

please advise. I have XML which i need to correct via php.

**example of XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csv_data>
<row>
    <articul>1107134</articul>
    <type>car tires</type>
    <brand>Aeolus</brand>
    <name>Aeolus AL01 Trans Ace 195/75 R16C 107/105R</name>
    <season>summer</season>
</row>
<row>
    <articul>1107134</articul>
    <type>car tires</type>
    <brand>Aeolus</brand>
    <name>Aeolus AL01 Trans Ace 195/75 R16 107/105R</name>
    <season>summer</season>
</row>
</csv_data>
```

In result I need replace in `<type>car tires</type>` to `<type>new car tires</type>`, if there is a value like "R16C" (or R12C, R13C etc) in `<name></name>`. Symbol "C" means "new car tires" type. Else leave the field name with no changes.

I've got error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xml-parser.php"

what to do, please advise

```
  $filename="./mos-test2.xml";
    $dom = simplexml_load_file($filename);

    foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    //print_r($node);
    if($node->nodeType==1){
    $OldJobId = $node->getElementsByTagName('name')->Item(0);
    $newelement = $dom->createElement('name','new car type'.$OldJobId->nodeValue); 
    $OldJobId->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $OldJobId);
    }
    }

    $str = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

Comment: I've posted an answer but it doesn't cover `the `Symbol C` part of your question, I'll update it in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get all the row nodes `$dom->getElementsByTagName('row');`
2. If `[A-Z]{1}\d{2}C`, matches inside `row` `nodeValue`, tire is new
3. Loop the `childNodes` of `row` until we find `localName` = **type**
4. Change the `child` `nodeValue` that was matched above to **new** + existing `nodeValue`

---

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents("file.xml"));
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('row');
foreach($rows as $row){
  if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{1}\d{2}C/', $row->nodeValue)){
     foreach($row->childNodes as $child) {
         if($child->localName == "type"){
             $child->nodeValue = "new ".$child->textContent;
        }
      }
   }
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/y4zfgL)

Answer (score 0):

As you use **SimpleXML**, you don't need to worry about **DOM** manipulations and can treat your XML object as **StdClass**:

```
$filename = "./mos-test2.xml";
$data = simplexml_load_file($filename);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (preg_match("/R\d{2}C/", $row->name) === 1) {
        $row->type = 'new ' . $row->type;
    }   
}

$str = $data->asXML();
```

As it is said in the name, **SimpleXml** keeps things simple.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all!

this code works for me

```
<?
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents("./mos-test2.xml"));
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('row');
foreach($rows as $row){
 if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{1}\d{2}C/', $row->nodeValue)){
     foreach($row->childNodes as $child) {
         if($child->localName == "type"){
             $child->nodeValue = "Легкогрузовые";
        }
      }
   }
}
$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$dom->save("./mos-test-ready.xml")
?>
```